# Ansible register fails when there is no output from shell command

Tags: ansible

I am trying to check if a service is running then register its output to some variable if its not running then start the service. Below is my Ansible playbook snippet.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: check if service is running
    shell: pgrep node
    register: pgrep
  - name: stop running service
    shell: pkill node
    when: pgrep.stdout_lines != ''
    tags:
    - stop
  - name: start running service
    shell: pkill node
    when: pgrep.stdout_lines == ''
    tags:
    - start
```

Now in the above case if the process is not running then the `pgrep node` command returns exit status code as 1 which fails the "check if service is running" tasks and aborts further execution of tasks. I know by setting `ignore_errors: true` will ignore the error and proceed ahead, but it fails the Ansible runs. Is there a way where we can handle this gracefully?

Comment: "*...will ignore the error and proceed ahead, but it fails the ansible runs.*" I don't understand what it means.

Comment: What i meant is that particular task to check if service is running still fails although the execution proceeds executing further tasks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [control what defines failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure) and set the condition to fail when the return code from `pgrep` is 2 or 3.

Per `man pgrep`:

```
 The pgrep and pkill utilities return one of the following values upon exit:

 0       One or more processes were matched.
 1       No processes were matched.
 2       Invalid options were specified on the command line.
 3       An internal error occurred.
```

So the Ansible task should look like:

```
- name: check if service is running
  shell: pgrep node
  register: pgrep
  failed_when: "pgrep.rc == 2 or pgrep.rc == 3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer for future reference.  How to kill multiple processes, should they exist.  Only indicate a change if rc==0.  Don't show failed unless it's rc==2 or rc==3.

```
- name: "Kill any processes"
  become: True
  vars:
    processes_to_kill: ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"]
  shell: "pkill -f {{ item }}"
  with_items: "{{ processes_to_kill }}"
  register: pkill
  failed_when: "pkill.rc == 2 or pkill.rc == 3"
  changed_when: "pkill.rc == 0"
```